# Vulkan vertex drawing order

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am currently getting into vulkan and am now at the point where I want to draw a qube with perspective projection. But the drawing order of the faces doesnt seem to woek right.

[image: qube]

This is the depth stencil info of my pipeline

```
const auto depth_stencil_state_create_info = VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo{
      .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_DEPTH_STENCIL_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
      .pNext = nullptr,
      .flags = 0,
      .depthTestEnable = true,
      .depthWriteEnable = true,
      .depthCompareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS,
      .depthBoundsTestEnable = false,
      .stencilTestEnable = false,
      .front = VkStencilOpState{},
      .back = VkStencilOpState{},
      .minDepthBounds = 0.0f,
      .maxDepthBounds = 1.0f
    };
```

And the rasterization into

```
const auto rasterization_stage_create_info = VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo {
      .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_RASTERIZATION_STATE_CREATE_INFO,
      .pNext = nullptr,
      .flags = 0,
      .depthClampEnable = false,
      .rasterizerDiscardEnable = false,
      .polygonMode = VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL,
      .cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_NONE,
      .frontFace = VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE,
      .depthBiasEnable = false,
      .depthBiasConstantFactor = 0.0f,
      .depthBiasClamp = 0.0f,
      .depthBiasSlopeFactor = 0.0f,
      .lineWidth = 1.0f
    };
```

I am using a vertex struct with a `glm::vec3` for position and color.

Those are my vertices

```
const auto vertices = std::vector<vertex>{
      // left face (white)
      {{-.5f, -.5f, -.5f}, {.9f, .9f, .9f}},
      {{-.5f, .5f, .5f}, {.9f, .9f, .9f}},
      {{-.5f, -.5f, .5f}, {.9f, .9f, .9f}},
      {{-.5f, .5f, -.5f}, {.9f, .9f, .9f}},
 
      // right face (yellow)
      {{.5f, -.5f, -.5f}, {.8f, .8f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, .5f, .5f}, {.8f, .8f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, -.5f, .5f}, {.8f, .8f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, .5f, -.5f}, {.8f, .8f, .1f}},
 
      // top face (orange, remember y axis points down)
      {{-.5f, -.5f, -.5f}, {.9f, .6f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, -.5f, .5f}, {.9f, .6f, .1f}},
      {{-.5f, -.5f, .5f}, {.9f, .6f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, -.5f, -.5f}, {.9f, .6f, .1f}},
 
      // bottom face (red)
      {{-.5f, .5f, -.5f}, {.8f, .1f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, .5f, .5f}, {.8f, .1f, .1f}},
      {{-.5f, .5f, .5f}, {.8f, .1f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, .5f, -.5f}, {.8f, .1f, .1f}},
 
      // nose face (blue)
      {{-.5f, -.5f, 0.5f}, {.1f, .1f, .8f}},
      {{.5f, .5f, 0.5f}, {.1f, .1f, .8f}},
      {{-.5f, .5f, 0.5f}, {.1f, .1f, .8f}},
      {{.5f, -.5f, 0.5f}, {.1f, .1f, .8f}},
 
      // tail face (green)
      {{-.5f, -.5f, -0.5f}, {.1f, .8f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, .5f, -0.5f}, {.1f, .8f, .1f}},
      {{-.5f, .5f, -0.5f}, {.1f, .8f, .1f}},
      {{.5f, -.5f, -0.5f}, {.1f, .8f, .1f}}
    };
```

And my indices

```
const auto indices = std::vector<sbx::uint32>{
      0,  1,  2,
      0,  3,  1,
      4,  5,  6,
      4,  7,  5,
      8,  9,  10,
      8,  11, 9,
      12, 13, 14, 
      12, 15, 13, 
      16, 17, 18,
      16, 19, 17,
      20, 21, 22,
      20, 23, 21
    };
```

Do you have any idears or hints where I sould look to solve this behaviour?
Has this even to do with the pipeline or am I on the wrong path?

Edit: Might that be a problem caused by vulkans coordiante system? And if so, how would I fix it?

Comment: For some reason your depth test isn't working. First your white face is drawn, then your yellow face is drawn overwriting some of white, then orange is drawn overwriting the top of white, then red overwrites the bottom of the yellow face, then blue overwrites the rest of white, and finally green overwrites the right of yellow and orange. Your depth stencil information looks correct, so we would need to see how it is setup in the rest of the pipeline. Also enable the debug layer and see if any warnings or errors are reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with vertex order since you're not culling backfaces:

```
  .cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_NONE,
```

If you're trying to avoid setting up a depth test by just drawing front faces, you need to change this to

```
  .cullMode = VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT,
```

and *then* you'll either be able to see only the front faces, and won't have this overlapping issue.  However, if your triangle winding is incorrect, the cube will look inverted.

Comment: Cull mode just determines whether or not the rasterizer will even generate pixels based on front vs back faces. That is completely disparate from the depth test. A back face will be at the same depth as a front face. If a triangle is further back than another triangle, then it is further back than another triangle, which way it was unwound doesn't matter at the point of the depth test.

Comment: I know how depth tests work.  My point was that if you're drawing a single cube and only rendering front faces you don't need a depth test at all, because if your triangle winding you can't accidentally draw triangles out of order, because as you said, the rasterizer discards all the back facing triangles.